# SyntaxError: invalid syntax with python2 and selenium in centos6.8

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, python-2.6, centos6.8

I run python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
# from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

profile = Options()
profile.headless = True
profile.add_argument('-width=800')
profile.add_argument('-height=600')

# display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
# display.start()

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=profile, executable_path='./geckodriver')

driver.get('http://192.168.1.3')
elem = driver.find_element_by_id('sitename').text
print(elem)
driver.quit()
```

I try run script with pyvirtualdisplay, but error is still here.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 4, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
  File "/opt/pyscript/venv/env_selenium/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa
  File "/opt/pyscript/venv/env_selenium/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 29, in <module>
    from selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver import WebDriver as RemoteWebDriver
  File "/opt/pyscript/venv/env_selenium/lib/python2.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 1115
    return {k: size[k] for k in ('width', 'height')}
                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I install also fontconfig freetype freetype-devel fontconfig-devel libstdc++ in CentOS. And I try run with browser phantomjs, this problem still here.
Version: CentOS 6.8, python 2.6.6, selenium PyVirtualDisplay 0.2.5, selenium 3.141.0
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an incompatibility between Selenium and Python2.6 around dictionary comprehensions, which is what this line is.

```
return {k: size[k] for k in ('width', 'height')}
```

The issue has been reported a while ago and closed [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/5018). Also, Python 2 has reached end of life, so without support to fix issues like the one you are facing, this should be a strong incentive to upgrade to Python 3.x.

The not ideal alternative - downgrade selenium.